# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in php

Tags: php, mysql

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   mysql_connect() in F:\xampp\htdocs\hms\includes\database.php:7 Stack
>   trace: #0 F:\xampp\htdocs\hms\init.php(8): db_connect() #1
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\hms\index.php(61):
>   require_once('F:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\hms\includes\database.php on line 7

Answer (score 0):

Acording to php.net:

> This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: can you suggest me the php excat version so i not get this error.because online its run fine in 7.2.23  but not working in 7.0.30 and 7.0

Comment: I could not have run with v7.2 either. You need to go back to a 5.x version, but better to forget that api.

Comment: MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension is better.